# How to: Custom Category Archive Page for custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created my archive-programs.php in a plugin with the below code:

```
$this->loader->add_filter('template_include', $plugin_public, 'programs_template');
public function programs_template($template) {
    if (is_post_type_archive('programs')) {
        $theme_files = array('archive-programs.php', 'Anthem/archive-programs.php');
        $exists_in_theme = locate_template($theme_files, false);
        if ($exists_in_theme != '') {
            return $exists_in_theme;
        } else {
            return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'archive-programs.php';
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

This works as expected(above code) and Im able to layout my programs archive into whatever I want. The problem now is I'm trying to create a page for the archive categories with the below code and it is not working.

```
$this->loader->add_filter('category_template', $plugin_public, 'programs_category_template');
public function programs_category_template($template) {
    if (is_post_type_archive('programs') && is_tax()) {
        $theme_files = array('archive-programs-category.php', 'Anthem/archive-programs-category.php');
        $exists_in_theme = locate_template($theme_files, false);
        if ($exists_in_theme != '') {
            return $exists_in_theme;
        } else {
            return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'archive-programs-category.php';
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Does anyone know how I could create a template for my Archive Categories. I don't want to manually create a template file for each category. The above code just loads the default Archive Category ptemplate

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the filter from `category_template` to [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include)

Comment: I tried template_include. Still the same,not loading the template

Comment: I use very similar code to load in taxonomy specific templates and it works just fine. Are you sure your if statements are returning the expected values? I assume your first `if (is_post_type_archive('programs') && is_tax())` is returning true, but I suspect your `$exists_in_theme` variable is returning the opposite of what you're expecting for some reason

Comment: if (is_post_type_archive('programs') && is_tax()) is returning false

Comment: The question I guess is how do I determine if the user is on a category of the programs archive page?

Comment: Interesting, I'd have assumed that was returning true. Can you see which of those statements is returning false?

Comment: Also you may want to see if using `is_category()` will work instead of `is_tax()` - there are a couple issues in core trac that show `is_tax()` not always working as expected

Comment: If it's `is_post_type_archive('programs')` that is returning false, you may have the registered post name wrong (perhaps registered without the 's' on the end?)

Comment: its the is_tax() and is_category() thats returning false. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Category template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/category_template) hook can only be used on default Wordpress categories, not taxonomies. If you try some simple code such as the following you will see that custom taxonomies or post type archives will not use the text.php file, but default WP categories will.

```
add_filter('category_template', 'testtemplates');
function testtemplates($template) {
    $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'text.php';
    return $template;
}
```

You need to use the [template_include](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter, first off.

You cannot use is_post_type_archive anymore because you are not in a post type archive anymore, but a taxonomy archive. So `is_post_type_archive()` returns false. `Is_tax()` is okay and will return true.

A good way to check the current taxonomy is using [get_queried_object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object). It has its own caveats but serves a good purpose here.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'programs_category_template');

function programs_category_template($template) {    
    $term = get_queried_object();   
    $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;

    $theme_files = array('archive-programs-category.php', 'Anthem/archive-programs-category.php');
    $exists_in_theme = locate_template($theme_files, false);

    $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'archive-programs-category.php';

    if ($taxonomy === 'programs' && is_tax()) { 
        $template = $exists_in_theme;   
    }

    return $template;
}
```

When using taxonomy terms (categories usually refers to default WP categories for the Posts post type) your [taxonomy template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) names should start with the taxonomy- keyword, not archive-. The archive keyword is reserved only for CPT archives, and shouldn't be used for taxonomy term archives. So, in this case, it would be taxonomy-program-category.php if your taxonomy term is named program-category.